# building .vdproject from powershell script

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have created a script for building a .vdproject in windows-powershell.

```
& "C:\VS_Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "E:\gitdownload\xxx-xxx-plugin-59bee0c0c3ef4279a310e95584ee6297d53106ea\IISPlugin\IISPlugin.sln" /rebuild Release /project "E:\gitdownload\xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-plugin-59bee0c0c3ef4279xxx\IISPlugin\xxx.HttpModule.IISxxxCollector.Setup\xxx.HttpModule.IISxxxCollector.Setup.vdproj"
```

However whenever i do so i get an error pop up
[image: Error PopUp]

I have seen this mentioned here
[Building setup project (.vdproj) from command line](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0ec5951d-d194-449e-8d59-705706ec888a/building-setup-project-vdproj-from-command-line?forum=winformssetup)

However trying that by changing my script to:-

```
& C:\VS_Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe "E:\gitdownload\xxx-xxx-xxx-plugin-59bee0c0c3ef4279axxx\IISPlugin\xxx.HttpModule.IISxxxCollector.Setup\xxx.HttpModule.IISxxxCollector.Setup.vdproj" /rebuild "Release|Any CPU"
```

also didnt fix the issue and i still continue to get the pop up.

**To build .vdproject manually in visual studio i have to install [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) plugin.However here from powershell i am unable to understand what to do after multiple tries and am stuck at this.**

Any Idea?

**Edit:-**

After **@rene** suggestion the pop up issue is gone but still running the command doesnt create the files .msi and setup.exe .In Visual studio i have to install InstallerProject extension to build .vdProject in order to get these files.However am at a loss about how to do this via powershell.I am completely stuck after various trials.

Comment: That dialog pops-up if any of the arguments is wrong. I don't see an argument named "/rebuild" so I'm not sure what you expect that option does. Did you try `/build` instead?

Comment: The dialog pop-up does go away using /build but still its not creating the msi set up file file that it should post building.When i do this from visual studio it does.It builds successfully and creates the set up file in a Release folder

Comment: You are arguments on the command line.  See following for different ways of handling the arguments : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: @jdweng i dont understand how this is releveant in this case.The ommand is running actually but somehow the build doesnt happen.This command is inside a script.The other commands in the script is working without any issues.Its just this one command thats not working

Comment: Are the other commands running an executable?  Read the popup.  Somehow this command is different from the others.  The popup looks like it is from the application.

Comment: The other commands are setting up an environment to run ms build and subsequently the devenv build in the script.msbuild runs perfectly.But its just this devenv build thats not woring